# Saving/Exporting Image Collection to asset in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, imagecollection

I am using MODIS image collection for irrigation mapping. Due to the outliers present in the MODIS dataset I applied Savitsky Golay filter in that image collection. And when doing other operation on that filtered image collection I'm getting  "User memory limit exceeded" problem. So is there any way whether I can save the filtered image collection to my assets and use that image collection for further operation so that there is no such problem.